# Some user enabled shortcut keys not working in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, batch-file

I like to think of myself as a power user and therefore I setup short cut keys on the keyboard to minimize steps for opening applications.

I have created a keyboard shortcut to a shortcut of a bat file - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> - which connects  to a mysql database for a website I administer. For whatever reason  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>S</kbd> has stopped working.

```
Ctrl + Alt + M = local mysql terminal
Ctrl + Alt + R = ruby terminal
Ctrl + Alt + P = python terminal
Ctrl + Alt + G = postresql terminal, no longer working
Ctrl + Alt + N = programmers notepad
Ctrl + Alt + S = opens shortcut of .bat file, no longer working
Ctrl + Alt + K = normal windows command prompt
```

The above programming languages can also be called through a normal command line as they are on my environment variable path. But I like these things accessible in multiple ways.

What does it mean when a shortcut key stops working all of a sudden? How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you install or upgrade any software recently that would (possibly) overwrite your custom shortcut keys?

Answer (score 1):

I would abandon native shortcuts and reach for [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.org), so you can easily [set up hotkeys and actions](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) you never dreamed of before – for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to show RGB color under cursor. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220666/in-notepad-change-tab-size-instantly/22880354#22880354) for AHK setup steps.

I would also recommend you using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> because the latter are (1) relatively often used inside applications (2) used to produce special chars (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> is equivalent to Right <kbd>Alt</kbd> on nearly any keyboard layout except of standard US. (Even on **US international** layout.)